# Why can't you compare Ints to Nums or Ords?

Tags: haskell, compare, typeclass

I have a function:

```
comp :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
comp a b = if a > b then True else False
```

This works. But if I do this:

```
comp :: (Num a) => Int -> a -> Bool
comp a b = if a > b then True else False
```

or this:

```
comp :: (Ord a) => Int -> a -> Bool
comp a b = if a > b then True else False
```

I get an error message:

> Could not deduce (a ~ Int)

Huh? Doesn't Num and Ord include Int? Aren't Num and Ord only supposed to include reals and not complex numbers?

Why is it that in the interpreter I can compare any real to any int:

```
4 > 4.5 
False
```

But I'm not allowed to define a function that compares Ints to Nums or Ords?

Comment: Never ever write `if p then True else False`.  This exactly the same is `p`.  Writing the former just shows you don't understand booleans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`>` expects two `Ord` instances of the same type.

```
ghci> :t (>)
(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

That type signature is not the same as `(Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b -> Bool`, which would be the signature of a function which can compare *any* two instances of `Ord`. (A non-trivial version of such a function does not exist.)

The reason `>` places such a draconian requirement on the poor programmer is that different types may have different ordering semantics. How would you compare an `Int` to a `[Bool]`?* Even though they are both instances of `Ord`, it doesn't make sense to compare them and the compiler won't allow it:

```
ghci> 3 > [True, True, False]

<interactive>:6:1:
    No instance for (Num [Bool]) arising from the literal `3'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Bool])
    In the first argument of `(>)', namely `3'
    In the expression: 3 > [True, True, False]
    In an equation for `it': it = 3 > [True, True, False]
```

**Each instance of `Ord` defines its own version of `>`**. That's why you can't compare an `Int` to a `Float`:

```
ghci> (3 :: Int) > (4 :: Float)

<interactive>:4:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
    In the second argument of `(>)', namely `(4 :: Float)'
    In the expression: (3 :: Int) > (4 :: Float)
    In an equation for `it': it = (3 :: Int) > (4 :: Float)
```

<sub>* To be pedantic, you *could* devise some way of representing an integer in binary as a list of booleans. Such a representation would be a good candidate for a `newtype` with its own instances of `Num` and `Ord`.</sub>

---

The reason `4 > 4.5` works is that the literal `4` is polymorphic. It can stand in for the '4' value of *any* numeric type:

```
ghci> :t 4
4 :: Num a => a
```

Similarly, `4.5` can take on any fractional type (`4.5 :: Fractional a => a`). The compiler is smart enough to realise that you are comparing a value of type "any number" to a value of type "any fractional number" and uses the most convenient concrete type available, which in this case is `Double`. (`Double` is declared as a `default` in the standard prelude.)
So in the expression `4 > 4.5`, **`4` and `4.5` will both be `Double`s.**

You can force the comparison to use the `Ord` instance of a particular concrete type by supplying a type signature to one of the operands.

Comment: So when you compare an int and a float in the interpreter, it actually converts the int to a float first before comparing? like 4 > 4.5 for example

Comment: @user2108462: No conversion is necessary: *both* are `Float`.  What happens is that 4 has type `Num a => a`, and 4.5 has type `Fractional a => a`.  Then `a` becomes `Float`.

Comment: @user2108462: You can test this for yourself: `(4 :: Int) > 4.5` is an error.

Comment: Hmm, okay that makes logical sense. But is there any mathematical reason why Ints can't be compared to Nums? In maths I can compare integers to real numbers, I mean integers ARE real numbers so why can't Haskell recognize that?

Comment: The literal `4` has a polymorphic value in Haskell, so that it can be assigned type `Int,Float,...` depending on the context. Roughly, you can pretend that numeric _constants_ are "converted" to any numeric type. Other numeric expressions (e.g. `x`) are never converted implicitly.

Comment: why are Ints not converted to Nums implicitly?

Comment: @user2108462 `Num` is not a type -- it is a collection of types. You say many times, "why can't I compare Ints to Nums" or "why can't I convert Ints to Nums" and similar things; but these things do not make sense! You can convert an Int to a value of another type in various ways; but you can't convert a value of one type to a value characterized by a *collection* of types. (Additionally: Haskell does not do any implicit conversion at all. You could wish it does, but would probably have to pay a price; for example, this would probably make type inference undecidable.)

Comment: @user2108462: The literal `4` is not an Int! It's a placeholder for the '4' value of _any numerical type_. Numeric literals are polymorphic.

Comment: That makes sense programmatically, but mathematically, integers can be compared to real numbers, so why can't the comparison operator treat all numbers (integers or not) as if they were Doubles?

Comment: @user2108462 You can do that, but you have to convert it using `fromIntegral`, which takes a value of any integer type and converts it to a value of any numeric type. `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

Comment: @user2108462 What if something is an `Integer` (an arbitrarily large integer that might not fit into a `Double`)?

Comment: @user2108462 There are more instances of `Num` than you know. There's `Int` and `Double`, yes, but also instances for complex numbers; lazy naturals with observable infinities; the computable reals; cyclotomic numbers; polynomials; numbers that only exist within a computational (applicative/monadic) context; reflections of the Haskell AST; automatic differentiation; and more. How could you possibly hope to sensibly compare an arbitrary pair of these things? Hell, some of these things--like complex numbers--don't even have a sensible way to compare to *themselves*!

Answer (score 4):

All the comparison operators in `Ord` have the type `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`, so you can only ever compare two values of the same type.

> Why is it that in the interpreter I can compare any real to any int:
>
> ```
> 4 > 4.5 
> False
> ```

You're not. You are comparing two `Double`s. Integer literals are overloaded in Haskell, so `4` can have any `Num` type depending on the context.

```
> :t 4
4 :: Num a => a
```

The same is true for decimal literals, which can be any `Fractional` type.

```
> :t 4.5
4.5 :: Fractional a => a
```

Based on these constraints, and the fact that the two sides should have the same type, it [defaults both sides to `Double`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4).

```
> :set -fwarn-type-defaults
> 4 > 4.5

<interactive>:6:5: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Double'
      (Fractional a0)
        arising from the literal `4.5' at <interactive>:6:5-7
      (Num a0) arising from the literal `4' at <interactive>:6:1
      (Ord a0) arising from a use of `>' at <interactive>:6:3
    In the second argument of `(>)', namely `4.5'
    In the expression: 4 > 4.5
    In an equation for `it': it = 4 > 4.5

<interactive>:6:5: Warning:
    Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Double'
      (Fractional a0)
        arising from the literal `4.5' at <interactive>:6:5-7
      (Num a0) arising from the literal `4' at <interactive>:6:1
      (Ord a0) arising from a use of `>' at <interactive>:6:3
    In the second argument of `(>)', namely `4.5'
    In the expression: 4 > 4.5
    In an equation for `it': it = 4 > 4.5
```

Comment: So why don't Ints get implicitly converted to Doubles for comparison? I mean in mathematics you can compare any integer to any real number.

Comment: @user2108462: Haskell never does any implicit number conversions, and that's a good thing. In exchange for being a little more explicit you eliminate an entire class of potential bugs.

Answer (score 3):

The type

```
comp :: (Num a) => Int -> a -> Bool
```

states that `comp` can work on an `Int` and any numeric type, i.e., a numeric type chosen by who calls this function. Since the caller can choose a complex type, it is impossible to implement `comp` in a meaningful way.

The type

```
comp :: (Ord a) => Int -> a -> Bool
```

states that `comp` can work on an `Int` and any ordered type, i.e., an ordered type chosen by who calls this function. Since the caller can choose `String`, or `(Int,Int)`, it is impossible to implement `comp` in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, but let's say you did want to write the function

```
comp :: (Num a, Ord a) => Int -> a -> Bool
```

The function you need is `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) =>  a -> b`.  One of the properties of a `Num` type in Haskell is that it must implement a sane version of this function. The resulting implementation would be

```
comp n x = fromIntegral n < x
```

Comment: Don't you have to convert Num to Ord first? So it'd be:

Comment: comp :: Num a => Ord a => Int -> a -> Bool

Comment: @user2108462, there was a problem (which I just edited away); the problem was that the `Num a` constraint does not imply the `Ord a` constraint. So that should be `comp :: (Num a, Ord a) => Int -> a -> Bool`. It looks like the syntax you used is correct also, but it does not seem to be in common use. This is not a matter of "converting Num to Ord" but rather of clarifying that `a` must be *both* `Num` and `Ord`.